# Haskell take and drop at the same time

Tags: string, function, haskell, take

I was wondering how can I achieve:

Taking the first n characters of a string then `++`(concatenating them with) drop these first n and take the next n and so on (without cutting words). I have tried function composition and `$` but the only thing I get, is errors.

**EDIT**

I am trying to align the text left for a given column width (n), that's why I try not to cut words, but if there is a word at the number n , just take some chars before it and then use \n to start again for the next line. My main problems so far are checking for the cut-words condition(I can use `!!` but should I use it in guards with map(-1) or how else) and implementing the recursion because as a base I got

```
take n s ++ "\n" ++ take n (drop n s)
```

and also the case where n is smaller than the longest word:

```
leftAlign n str = if n < ((maximum . map length . words) str) then "" else leftAlign n str
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and where you stuck?

Comment: I have removed your last sentence; it is too easy to interpret it as a snarky comment about Haskell and its practitioners. In case it was intended to be that way: don't do that again.

Comment: At chi's prompting: what exactly does "without cutting words" mean? I'm not sure I understand the question yet.

Comment: I am trying to align the text left for a given column width, that's why I try not to cut words, but if there is a word at the number n , just take some chars before it and then use `\n` to start again for the next line.

Comment: @user4325010 Define "word"; it may be obvious to you, but "word" is a very fluid concept. Also, are you sure you don't want to write a (simple) parser for this kind of task, instead of relying only on `take` and `drop`?

Comment: @Jubobs Words are substrings divided with space (`" \t\n"`). Well, such parser implementation would be interesting to see and I have turned to `take` and `drop` only because it was the obvious.

Comment: I think @Jubobs is right. You basically want a parser whose state includes a letter count along with the string.

Comment: In answer to the question *title*: yes, there is a function that drops and takes at the same time: it's called `splitAt`. There's also an equivalent function for `dropWhile`/`takeWhile`.

Comment: This works, although it's a tad convoluted: https://gist.github.com/SwiftsNamesake/4a3080fb7de41cb8e89604445d712940

Answer (score -1):

[`Data.List.Split.chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) does this.

Comment: The OP specified "without cutting words", so a bit more care is needed.